# How to upgrade ruby software to Ruby 1.9.3-p385 using sudo?

Tags: 12.10, ruby

I had installed it using `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3`.

I am using `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`in my laptop. Now I want to upgrade it more latest version `Ruby 1.9.3-p385`.

One of my confusion is why the latest version is not getting installed,with the above command? Is ruby `Ruby 1.9.3-p385` not compatible with Ubuntu 12.10 version?

How to do that using `sudo`,except `rvm` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone else has posted steps for exactly what you're looking to do. Start on step # 2.

[Install Ruby from source](http://paul-wong-jr.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-and-compiling-ruby-from.html)

Comment: when I installed it very few days back I just did `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3` and everything was installed properly. but the version was not the current one what I mentioned in my description. Thus I want something like the previous if any to upgrade it.

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU, there is no way to "upgrade" Ruby. You should consider installing and using RVM, it's meant to handle situations just like this. Or download, install and compile Ruby from source each time you want a different version.

Comment: There's a similar question on stackoverflow, which is geared more toward programmers than askubuntu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078166/how-do-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-without-rvm

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try RVM - Ruby Version Manager. 
A simple command :

```
rvm gemset update
```

will do the magic for you.